# Use JavaScript object in background.js file to populate HTML in new chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to build a Chrome extension that allows the user to grab all of their open URLs and then display it on a new tab (eventually I want to allow the user to send the data to a database).  I can capture all of the tabs in the current Window, but I'm having trouble taking that data and using it in the newly created tab.

Here's how my project is configured now:

`Manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "ExplodeSlideshow",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description" : "This Chrome extension allows you to click on all of the links in a Slideshow (opened in a New Tab) and then save those links to a database.",
  "icons": { "16": "icons/16x16.png", "48": "icons/48x48.png", "128": "icons/128x128.png" },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19x19.png",
      "38": "icons/38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "That's the tool tip",
    "default_popup": "browseraction/popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js", "populate_content.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  // "chrome_url_overrides" : {
  //   "newtab": "newtab/newtab.html"
  // },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`background.js`

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch(request.type) {
        case "capture-tabs":
            getWindowUrls();
        break;
    }
    return true;
});

var getWindowUrls = function() {
  // get current browser window
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(win) {

    // alert(JSON.stringify(win));

    // get an array of the tabs in the window
    chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(win.id, function(tabs) {

      var activeUrl = "";
      var activeUrlId = null;
      var urls = [];

      for (i in tabs) {
        if (tabs[i].active === true) {
          // save current tab's id & URL
          activeUrl = tabs[i].url
          activeUrlId = tabs[i].id
        } else {
          // capture other tabs' id & URL
          urls.push({id: tabs[i].id, url: tabs[i].url});
        }
      }

      // alert(JSON.stringify(activeUrl));
      // alert(JSON.stringify(urls));

      // open new tab
      chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: 'newtab/newtab.html'}, function (tab) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(tab));

        // populate HTML
        // NEED HELP HERE

        // remove original tab
        chrome.tabs.remove(activeUrlId, function() {});

        // close newly opened tabs
        for (i in urls) {
          chrome.tabs.remove(urls[i].id, function() {});
        }

      });

    });
  });

}
```

`browseraction/popup.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
<div style="width:200px">
    <button id="button">Capture Tabs</button>
</div>
```

`browseraction/popup.js`

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({
            type: "capture-tabs"
        });
    }
}
```

`newtab/newtab.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">


        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Explode Slideshows | Chrome Extension</h1>
            <h4>Origin Page: <span id="origin"></span></h4>
            <ul id="other_tabs">

            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="populate_content.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`newtab/populate_content.js`

```
(function() {
  var origin_element = document.getElementById("origin");
  var other_tabs_element = document.getElementById("other_tabs");

  origin_element.innerHTML += activeUrl;
})();
```

When I attempt to use this Chrome extension I can click on the button in the `popup.html` and it grabs all of the tabs, stores them in a variable, opens a new tab, destroys the other tabs.  But I have trouble populating the HTML of the newly created tab -- I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: activeUrl is not defined.`  So, my question is **how do I pass the JavaScript objects (`activeUrl` and `urls`) from the `background.js` `getWindowUrls()` method and use to populate HTML in my `newtab/newtab.html` file?**

Comment: Look into `$.getJSON()` and `window.open()`. You can leave off `window`, since it's implicit, and just use `open()`, if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your new tab isn't directly linked to the background page.  So your new tab wont be able to access any variables stored in background.js.  you can use messaging, however i find that saving and using a window variable is easier:

example new tab:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(window){
    var backgroundpage=window;
    backgroundpage.activeUrl;//equals "foo"
    backgroundpage.executeFunction("hi");//returns "hello!"
});
```

example background page:

```
var activeUrl="foo";

function executeFunction(message){
   if(message=="hi"){
       return "hello!";//or an object, number, array, ect.
   }else{
       return "what did you say?";
   }
}
```

Popups also support this.  Content scripts dont.

Have your background page save all relevant information into a variable.
When your new tab loads, have it grab that variable and pupulate itself.
The background page should not be in charge of pupulating the html.